# Is async/await approach to promises bad when using RTK Query?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rtk-query

Just joined a project where RTK Query is being implemented for the first time in React Native.  This seems to be the rest of the team's first time working with RTK Query.  The way things are currently set up, they're often using something like

```
const [someFunctionality] = useSomeFunctionalityMutation();

return async (someParams) => { 
const response = await someFunctionality(someParams)

if ('data' in response) { dispatch(successAction) }
else if ('error' in response) { 
  dispatch(errorAction); 
  setSomeState(error); 
} 
}
```

I'm fairly early in my career and have only worked with RTK Query on one previous project.  In situations where we wanted to run a side effect as a result of a mutation, we'd go with some like

```
const [someFunctionality] = useSomeFunctionalityMutation();

someFunctionality(someParams)
  .unwrap()
  .then(() => dispatch(successAction))
  .catch((error) => {
    dispatch(errorAction);
    setSomeState(error);
  }
```

though we were never writing it as a reusable function.

The first approach seems to work without issue, but I was wondering:

Is one approach preferred to the other? Why? Will the first approach potentially cause issues that aren't being noticed in basic testing?  Since this functionality is new to many on the team, I want to make sure we're establishing good standards. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Promise chaining and `async..await` are just two different notations for the same functionality. You could just as well write

```js
async function someFn() {
  try {
    const result = await someFunctionality(someParams).unwrap();
    dispatch(successAction)
  } catch {
    dispatch(errorAction);
    setSomeState(error);
  }
}
```

That said, you should probably not dispatch actions like that. For one, you could do that in endpoint lifecycle instead of in your component, and on the other hand, usually you don't need to do that at all, as your slice for `errorAction` or `successAction` could also add `extraReducers` for `api.endpoints.someFunctionality.matchFulfilled`, which would mean that you don't need any extra dispatched action at all.

Comment: Do you know if there's anything about RTK Query that would make the .unwrap().then().catch() preferable to the async/await approach? I just see .unwrap().then().catch() mentioned in RTK Query's mutation docs, so I wasn't sure if  there was a specific reason why. The use of .unwrap() in general is different than the old try/catch that was commonly used with promises.

Comment: As the author of RTK Query: no. That is literally impossible, because, as I said: those are the same language feature, just different ways of writing it.
The only thing is that you have to `.unwrap` in both cases, so you have a promise that actually returns a value and throws an error - if you don't unwrap, you will get a promise of the last action instead, and that will always resolve peacefully.